# Can I use a scss Function without importing it every time?

Tags: function, sass

I am currently working with a scss function which I have in my util/functions.scss file but currently I have to import it every-time I create a new scss file on the top with
`@use "util/functions" as *;`

Is there a way to globally reference the function one time so I don't have to add the @use on every new file?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a bundle.scss and only add includes of your scss files in it.
Place your Variable,functions and mixins at the top and your scss files below.
Rename included files with `_` for better visibility.
Let your scss build task only built the bundle.

Like this the built task knows your functions and variables, and uses it for all included files.

Example from my Include file with bootstrap:

```
// Functions
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "project/src/Scss/custom-functions";

// Variables
@import "project/src/Scss/custom-variables";

@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";

// Bootstrap
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";

//your scss
@import "project/src/Scss/custom-element-style"
```

`_` and `.scss` file ending isn't needed in my case.